# PyLatex prints names of packages at the top of the document

Tags: python, pylatex

When i am trying to compile the LaTeX template that i have in a file using PyLatex, pdf that is getting generated have names of packages used at the top of the document. What may be a reason of that? File generates properly using TeXstudio. [image]

```
latex_document = 

os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'path')
with open(latex_document, encoding = 'UTF-8') as file:
    tex= file.read()    
doc = Document('name')

doc.packages.append(Package('tabularx'))
[...]
doc.append(NoEscape(tex))
doc.generate_pdf(compiler='C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex', clean_tex=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you extend your fragment into an example we can copy and paste into VS Code or so and troubleshoot your issues? It is not apparent from your fragment what the issue is so we need more information please